# Overriding FullCalendar calendar.prev and calendar.next behaviour

Tags: javascript, view, calendar, fullcalendar

I have a calendar where one of the views is for 2 months. When clicking the Prev and Next buttons the default behaviour for this view is to skip back two months or skip forward two months. What I want to achieve, if I click the next button for example, and I'm viewing March/April,is to change the display to April/May and not May/June.

Is this possible?

Comment: I assume this is part of a custom view? Can we have a [mre] of the issue please?

Answer (score 1):

I have actually managed to solve the problem as follows. I am using FullCalendar Scheduler with the following views -

```
            views: {
            resourceTimelineDay: {
                buttonText: 'Day',
                type: 'resourceTimeline',
                slotDuration: '00:05:00',
                slotLabelInterval: '00:30:00',
                slotLabelFormat: [{year: 'numeric', month: 'long', day: 'numeric', weekday: 'long'}, {hour: '2-digit', minute: '2-digit', omitZeroMinute: false, meridiem: 'short'}]
            },
            resourceTimelineWeek: {
                buttonText: 'Week',
                type: 'resourceTimeline',
                slotDuration: '01:00:00',
                slotLabelInterval: '2:00:00',
                slotLabelFormat: [{year: 'numeric', month: 'long', day: 'numeric', weekday: 'short'}, {hour: '2-digit', minute: '2-digit', omitZeroMinute: false, meridiem: 'short'}]
            },
            resourceTimelineMonth: {
                buttonText: 'Month',
                type: 'resourceTimeline',
                slotDuration: '02:00:00',
                slotLabelInterval: '24:00:00',
                slotLabelFormat: [{year: 'numeric',month: 'long'},{day: 'numeric', weekday: 'short'}]
            },
            resourceTimelineTwoMonths: {
                buttonText: '2 Months',
                type: 'resourceTimeline',
                duration: { months: 2},
                slotDuration: '02:00:00',
                slotLabelInterval: '24:00:00',
                slotLabelFormat: [{month: 'long'},{day: 'numeric'}]
            }
        },
```

I have created a couple of custom buttons to select prev and next periods. view3 is set depending which view button is clicked -

```
                periodPrev: {
                text: 'Prev', icon: 'chevron-left', click: function(){
                    if(view3 == '2 months')
                        {
                        let currentStart = new Date(periodStart);
                        let updatedStart = new Date(currentStart.setMonth(currentStart.getMonth()-1));
                        periodStart = moment(updatedStart).format('YYYY-MM-DD');
                        calendar.gotoDate(periodStart);
                        calendar.render();
                        }
                    else
                        {
                        calendar.prev();
                        }
```

and

```
            periodNext: {
                text: 'Next', icon: 'chevron-right', click: function(){
                    if(view3 == '2 months')
                        {
                        let currentStart = new Date(periodStart);
                        let updatedStart = new Date(currentStart.setMonth(currentStart.getMonth()+1));
                        periodStart = moment(updatedStart).format('YYYY-MM-DD');
                        calendar.gotoDate(periodStart);
                        calendar.render();
                        }
                    else
                        {
                        calendar.next();    
                        }
```

The standard calendar.prev and calendar.next is called if the view isn't '2 months'. Otherwise the date is manipulated and results in the 2 month view incrementing or decrementing by one month.